# Deja Backup to Amazon S3 text-only possible?

Tags: command-line, backup, deja-dup, duplicity

I have an old laptop which a defect graphics card so that I can run only ubuntu text only. Is it possible to run deja backup from command line to backup to Amazons S3?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deja Dup is a slick front end to the [Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) tool, so you can just use duplicity on a console system in this manner.

You can find the information for the flags to use S3 in the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/duplicity.1.html).

ECII found a blog explaining the whole procedure and setup in order to do S3 backups on text-only Ubuntu

- http://blog.damontimm.com/bash-script-incremental-encrypted-backups-duplicity-amazon-s3/
- http://blog.damontimm.com/how-to-automated-secure-encrypted-incremental-backups-amazon-s3-duplicity-os-x-or-ubuntu/